# ¿Como integrar 'swipe' de Hammer.js en Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone

¡Hola!

Llevo todo el día intentando hacer que un swipe funcione con backbone y no he tenido suerte. Tengo un código que funciona pero es bastante feo y por lo que he visto se puede estructurar mejor. El problema es que cuando lo inento integrar en Backbone no me funciona nada. El código que está comentado es el que funciona.

He intentado seguir [este artículo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449649/how-to-swipe-an-element-using-hammer-js-in-backbone-view), y [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262201/mobile-gestures-in-backbone-js), y [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079136/how-to-get-hammer-js-to-work-with-backbone) ...

¿Alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal?

```
var app = app || {};

$(function () {

  app.tabsContent = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagname: '#tabs-container',

    events: {
      'swipe #tabs-header': 'swipeIt'
    },

    initialize: function () {
      this.$list = $('#group-list');

      this.$el.hammer();


      // let swipeTabs = document.getElementById('tabs-header');
      // let mc = new Hammer(swipeTabs);
      // mc.get('swipe').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });
      // mc.on("swipe", this.swipeIt);

      app.groupCollection.fetch();
      this.listenTo(app.groupCollection, 'add', this.appendOne);
    },

    render: function () {

    },

    appendOne: function (group) {
      let view = new app.GroupView({model: group});
      this.$list.append(view.render().el);
    },

    swipeIt: function (e) {
      if (e.direction == 8) {
        console.log('Swipe up')
      } else if (e.direction == 16) {
        console.log('Swipe down')
      }

    }
  })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno me respondo a mi mismo por si le puede servir a alguien de ayuda.

Resulta que estaba confundiendo en backbone `tagname` y `el` como cosas similares, utilizando `tagname` en lugar the `el` que entre otras cosas evitaba que se ejecutara el evento.

Después he añadido el plugin de jQuery para hammer.js y he modificado la forma de llamar al objeto hammer según como dice la [documentacion](http://hammerjs.github.io/jquery-plugin/):

```
var app = app || {};

$(function () {

app.tabsContent = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#tabs-container',

  events: {
  'swipe #tabs-header': 'swipeIt'
  },

  initialize: function () {
    this.render();
  },

  render: function () {
    //Cambio la forma de llamar al objeto hammer.

    let mc = this.$tabsHeader.hammer();

    //Para añadir swipeUp a hammerjs ya que no lo tiene por defecto.

    mc.data('hammer').get('swipe').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });
  },

  swipeIt: function (e) {
    if (e.gesture.offsetDirection == 8) {
      console.log('Swipe up')
    } else if (e.gesture.offsetDirection == 16) {
      console.log('Swipe down')
    }

  }
})   
})
```